# sunday to saturday week date array in php

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.6

for getting sunday to saturday dates for calender week i am using that code in php  :

```
$dt = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

    $res['start'] = date('N', $dt)==1 ? date('Y-m-d', $dt) : date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last sunday', $dt));

    $res['end'] = date('N', $dt)==7 ? date('Y-m-d', $dt) : date('Y-m-d', strtotime('saturday', $dt));

    $day_of_week = date('N', strtotime($res['start']));


    $given_date = strtotime( $res['end'] );

    $first_of_week =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime("- {$day_of_week} day", $given_date));

    $first_of_week = strtotime($first_of_week);

    for($i=1 ;$i<=7; $i++)
    {
        $datess[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+ {$i} day", $first_of_week));

        $week_array[] = date('m/d', strtotime("+ {$i} day", $first_of_week));
  print_r($datess);
    }
exit;
```

after this i am getting array from 2018-10-29  to 2018-11-04 but i want array from 2018-11-04 2018-11-10 what i am doing wrong here in this code can anyone please let me know or correct me where i am doing wrong in this code

Comment: Any suggestion or loop hole ???please let me know

Comment: Use [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) instead, https://3v4l.org/TEb4G

Comment: This code seems quite complicated for a rather simple task. Here's a simpler version using DateTime Class: https://3v4l.org/JhsIj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you assuming Sunday is day of the week number `1`? And Saturday `7`?

If so, Sunday is `7` and Saturday `6`. So your code would look like this:

```
$dt = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

$res['start'] = date('N', $dt) == 7 ? date('Y-m-d', $dt) : date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last sunday', $dt));

$res['end'] = date('N', $dt) == 6 ? date('Y-m-d', $dt) : date('Y-m-d', strtotime('saturday', $dt));

$day_of_week = date('N', strtotime($res['start']));


$given_date = strtotime($res['end']);

$first_of_week =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime("- {$day_of_week} day", $given_date));

$first_of_week = strtotime($first_of_week);

for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 7; $i++) {
    $datess[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+ {$i} day", $first_of_week));

    $week_array[] = date('m/d', strtotime("+ {$i} day", $first_of_week));
    print_r($datess);
}
```

Comment: Elliot Reed@ thanx helps me alot

Answer (score 0):

One solution using PHP powerful date functions [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
<?php

if (date('D') == 'Sun') {
    $lsTimestamp = time();
} else {
    $lsTimestamp = strtotime('last Sunday');
}

$dates = [date('Y-m-d', $lsTimestamp)];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+' . $i . ' day', $lsTimestamp));
}

var_dump($dates);
```